# Syntax for defining const array type

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, constants, language-lawyer

Be warned, I'm just interested in the possibility of C++ syntax, not in any practical use.

It easy to define an array type. As an example, `int a[3];` defines an array type of 3 `int`, while `const int a[3];` or `int const a[3];` defines an array type of 3 `const int`. None of the three forms actually defines a **const array** of some type `T` (which itself can be const-modified, of course). Consequently, the following code will not compile:

```
void f(int (&a)[3]) {...}

f({1, 2, 3});
```

The reason is simple: a non-const lval reference cannot be bound to an rval temporary. One way to correct the code would be:

```
typedef int ArrOfInt[3];

void f(const ArrOfInt& a) {...}

f({1, 2, 3});
```

My question is: does C++ have syntax for an inline definition of const array type, so that there is no need for a `typedef` in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays do not have separate cv-qualification from their elements, so you are asking for something that does not exist. Quoth the standard,

> Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type (8.3.4).

([basic.type.qualifier]/2 in N3936)

However, it goes on to say that when the element type is qualified, the array type is considered to be qualified too:

> ... An array type whose elements are
>   cv-qualified is also considered to have the same cv-qualifications as its elements.

([basic.type.qualifier]/5)

And the code you wrote can indeed be rewritten without a typedef. The declarator syntax is

```
void f(const int (&a)[3]);
```

The `const` still attaches to the element type, but the array type is also `const`, so the reference is an lvalue reference to a `const` type. So that's why it can bind to a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

This was subject of core issue [**#1059**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1059):

> There does not appear to be a definitive normative statement answering
>   the question of whether an array with a const-qualified element type
>   is itself const-qualified; [...]

... which was resolved just after C++11 was ratified. Now [basic.type.qualifier]/5 reads:

> Cv-qualifiers applied to an array type attach to the underlying
>   element type, so the notation “*cv* `T`,” where `T` is an array type, refers
>   to an array whose elements are so-qualified. **An array type whose
>   elements are cv-qualified is also considered to have the same
>   cv-qualifications as its elements.**

Thus it's impossible to make the array elements `const` but not the enclosing array itself, and vice versa.
E.g.

```
const int arr[2];
```

Here, `arr` is (top-level) `const` (`std::is_const<decltype(arr)>{}` is `true`) and so are its elements. And in

```
void f(const (&a)[3]) {...}
```

`a` refers to a `const` array with `const` elements.

Comment: So the current GCC, clang, and VC are just not standard-conformant for not compiling the first version of the code?

Comment: @Lingxi The first version of the code doesn't have any `const` anywhere. And if I change it to `const int (&a)[3]`, then GCC does accept that. So does clang.

Comment: @Lingxi The first version of your code is just incorrect.

Comment: Ah, yes. I just forgot that.